# Tensor product of algebras and generating sets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a module over $k$ generated by $x$ and $y$. The generating set for $A \otimes_k A$ is $\{x \otimes x, x \otimes y, y \otimes x, y \otimes y\}$. But does this still hold if $A$ is an *algebra* over $k$?

So, for instance, $(x \otimes y)(x \otimes x) = (x^2 \otimes yx)$ is also an element of $A \otimes_k A$ but the generating set mentioned above does not span it, right? Does this mean that if $A$ is a finite $k$-algebra, then $A \otimes_k A$ is not necessarily finite?

Comment: A proper generating set for $A \otimes_k A$ *as an algebra* would be $x \otimes 1, y \otimes 1, 1 \otimes x, 1 \otimes y$, provided that $x, y$ was a generating set for $A$ *as an algebra*. (Unless your algebras are non-unital -- then it can indeed happen that $A \otimes_k A$ has no finite set of generators even though $A$ has.)